# Why does popViewControllerAnimated:YES occasionally not animate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

This only happens from time to time, seems random and I have not been able to recreate this bug in order to track it down.

I know this is not much information and there might be thousands of issues which might cause this strange behavior. But maybe you can point me to those most obvious or give me a hint how to solve my problem or just tell me what to do in the next step.

**UPDATE:** @Błażej pointed out that the main (UI) thread might be busy. It seems I have now minimized this behavior by removing all animations on the views of the viewcontroller which I was popping before popping it. I did something like this:

```
[self.mapView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

But if I keep on navigating back and forth as crazy I still notice popping without animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no issues in your code at all. Animations in iOS run on real-time threads, so when the device is not able to calculate an animation in a scheduled time it just abandons it, that's why your views might pop without animation from time to time. Then again, perhaps it's your app that keeps the main (UI) thread busy, hence no animations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Błażej! Is there a way I can detect whether the main (UI) thread is busy? I guess not. Maybe I would set a small timeout for my animation. What is the best approach to handle this issue?

Comment: There is, you can run your app with Instruments (product->profile in xcode) and check option "separate by thread", the main one will be labeled with "main".In general you shouldn't do anything else then UI manipulations on the main thread, it's really fast and easy to move the work to other threads with GCD (and back to the main thread).